# How to focus the textbox Within the table using ng-change in angularjs webapi?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive

When I change the quantity, the quantity focus is lost..
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyFFF.png)

AngularJS Code: ng-change code

```
$scope.txtqty = function (item) {
    var id = item.Id;
    $http.put("/api/Products/txtqty/" + id, item).then(function (response) {
        $scope.gridproducts = response.data;
    })
}
```

HTML table code

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in gridproducts">
            <td ng-click="griddelete(item.Id)"><a class="delete"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a></td>
            <td class="name">{{item.ProductName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ProductRate}}</td>
            <td><input class="form-control qty" type="text" style="width:50px" ng-change="txtqty(item)" ng-model="item.ProductQty" value="{{item.ProductQty}}"></td>
            <td>{{item.TotalAmount}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th colspan="2"><b>Total</b></th>
            <th><b>{{gridproducts[0].TotalBill}}</b></th>
            </tr><tr>
            <th colspan="2"><b></b></th>
            <th colspan="2"><b>Total Items</b></th>
            <th><b>25</b></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

> Webapi Controller code this is webapi controller here you can see the

```
 [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Products/txtqty/{id}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PuttxtQTY(int id, Product Pro)
        {
            var q = gridlist.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (q != null)
            {
                q.ProductQty = Pro.ProductQty;
                q.TotalAmount = q.ProductQty * q.ProductRate;
                q.TotalBill = gridlist.Sum(x => x.TotalAmount);
                foreach (var item in gridlist)
                {
                    item.TotalBill = q.TotalBill;
                }
            }
            return Ok(gridlist);
        }
```

Comment: First of all, it's not *ng-onchange*, it's `ng-change`, as in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). Secondly, what do you mean by *When I change the quantity, the quantity focus is lost* ... what focus? Input field focus?

Comment: ok thanks your response... mean when i change quantity the after update(qty*price)than  textbox is unfocus...i want t focus the textbox after update

Comment: please see the screenshot

Comment: Sorry man but I don't see any textbox in the code nor the in the screenshot ... are you referring to the input? And can you please attach the code for that?

Comment: <td><input class="form-control qty" type="text" style="width:50px" ng-change="txtqty(item)" ng-model="item.ProductQty" value="{{item.ProductQty}}"></td>
            this is textbox within table

Comment: see on the top ( click here to see image ) this is write on the top click this

Comment: Are you using a spinner or some other library that could intercept the HTTP request?

Comment: now i share the the webapi code please see again

Comment: Hi Umar, you want the input box text should be focused when you are changing it or input box should be focused

Answer (score 0):

You could give each input a unique ID and manually re-focus it as such:

HTML with ID on input

`<td><input class="form-control qty" type="text" id="productQty_{{item.id}}" style="width:50px" ng-change="txtqty(item)" ng-model="item.ProductQty" value="{{item.ProductQty}}"></td>`

Function adjusted with re-focus logic

```
$scope.txtqty = function (item) {
    var id = item.Id;
    $http.put("/api/Products/txtqty/" + id, item).then(function (response) {
        $scope.gridproducts = response.data;
        document.getElementById("productQty_" + id).focus();
    })
}
```

Hope this does the job :)